# Запуск нескольких активностей при быстром нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, android

Заметил, что в приложении, в котором есть listview и вторая активность при простом нажатии на элемент listview все хорошо переходит на вторую активность, но вот, если начать быстро "тыкать" на элемент listview откроется как минимум две активности. Открывается одна и тут же она же открывается еще раз. И вот, если надо возвратиться назад к listview приходиться на кнопку назад тоже нажимать как минимум два раза. Хотелось бы спросить за счет чего это происходит и как можно было бы это исправить?

Comment: в манифесте для активности пропишите android:launchMode="singleTask"

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете реализовать Debouncer который не позволяет слишком часто нажимать на кнопку. Например не чаще чем раз в секунду.

Можно написать что-то вроде такого:

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

/**
* A Debounced OnClickListener 
* Rejects clicks that are too close together in time.
* This class is safe to use as an OnClickListener for multiple views, and will debounce each one separately.
*/ 
public abstract class DebouncedOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener { 

    private final long minimumIntervalMillis; 
    private Map<View, Long> lastClickMap; 

    /**
    * Implement this in your subclass instead of onClick 
    * @param v The view that was clicked 
    */
    public abstract void onDebouncedClick(View v);

    /** 
    * The one and only constructor 
    * @param minimumIntervalMillis The minimum allowed time between clicks - any click sooner than this after a previous click will be rejected
    */ 
    public DebouncedOnClickListener(long minimumIntervalMillis) {
        this.minimumIntervalMillis = minimumIntervalMillis; 
        this.lastClickMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
    } 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View clickedView) { 
        Long previousClickTimestamp = lastClickMap.get(clickedView); 
        long currentTimestamp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        lastClickMap.put(clickedView, currentTimestamp);
        
        if(previousClickTimestamp == null || Math.abs(currentTimestamp - previousClickTimestamp) > minimumIntervalMillis) { 
            onDebouncedClick(clickedView); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Если вы используете RX Java, то там уже есть встроенные решения. Ну или вы можете поискать другие реализации дебаунсеров.

Comment: Больше спасибо!